# Помогите переписать JQuery на JavaScript - MixitUP Select на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, фильтрация, фильтры

помогите реализовать фильтрацию. Нужно заставить плагин MixitUp работать с селектами, в принципе решение есть на JQuery но к сожалению я его не знаю и JS только недавно начал изучать.
Собственно помогите этот кот переписать в JS

```js
$(function(){
  var $filterSelect = $('#FilterSelect'),
      $sortSelect = $('#SortSelect'),
      $container = $('#Container');
  
  $container.mixItUp();
  
  $filterSelect.on('change', function(){
    $container.mixItUp('filter', this.value);
  });
  
  $sortSelect.on('change', function(){
    $container.mixItUp('sort', this.value);
  });
});
```

Вот я что я пытался сделать, но не хватает знаний(

```js
const filterSelect = document.getElementById('FilterSelect')
const sortSelect = document.getElementById('SortSelect')
const container = document.getElementById('Container')

container.mixItUp()

filterSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    container.mixItUp(filter, e.target.value)
  })
```

Comment: `querySelectorById` не требует `#` и пробелы - лишнее

Comment: со скобками нужно аккуратнее `addEventListener` - метод